# If cells 1A,1B,1C contain X then sum 2A, 2B, 2C respectively

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, average, countif

I'm trying to create make it so that, referring to the inserted picture, let's take the first row (row 6), and if N6 has a H in it then count the value two columns down (i.e., the value in P3), otherwise don't count this value.

Then do the same for U6, meaning if there is a H in this U6 then count the value two columns down in W1. After counting all the values the qualify find their mean average.

I tried several functions including COUNT and COUNTIF but I don't know how to make a value from another cell get selected if a certain text cell is true in a separate cell, and then how to repeat this and find the average of the selected values in the qualifying cells.

Here's an example of what I've tried but no luck:

```
=nb.si(N6,"*H*",P6)
```

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the quick answers. When I type in the formula and enter nothing seems to happen and formula just stays in the cell rather than turning into an answer. Maybe I didn't explain the problem that well so I will try again as this could help solve the problem. If there is a H in one cell the cell two columns down,same row, should be counted, otherwise it should not be counted. Then at the end you should end up with one summed figure divided by the number of figures which were counted. As I didn't mention the new value going into a cell not in the photo that could have been misleading.

Comment: Please ignore the previous comment I left - it turns out I sillily had text format on cell and  thus formulas were not being applied. All the solutions worked well so thanks for your help gtwebb, pnuts, and PermaNoob ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're using the French version of Excel, right? Just in case, I'll post it in English and French.

Keep in mind this would get pretty long if you wanted to do more, but you could do that with this formula:

French:

```
=(SI(N6="H";P6;0)+SI(U6="H";W6;0)+SI(AB6="H";AD6;0))/(SI(N6="H";1;0)+SI(U6="H";1;0)+SI(AB6="H";1;0))
```

English:

```
=(IF(N6="H",P6,0)+IF(U6="H",W6,0)+IF(AB6="H",AD6,0))/(IF(N6="H",1,0)+IF(U6="H",1,0)+IF(AB6="H",1,0))
```

Comment: Hi there PermaNoob, cheers for noticing that yes it is in French though any language will do. Still I appreciate you taking the time and effort to do it in both language and nice one for knowing it's in French rather than another language! Unfortunately, as I explained to gtwebb and pnuts I seem to be making a mistake because even when inputting your formula and I press enter the vale in cell L6 for example does not change. What do you think I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: As I wrote to the comment to my post changing the cell from text to number made the formula work. I really liked this formula because it meant I could write everything out in one cell without having to create different cells for two values which are the total number counted and total quantity of numbers used and then divide them. Again also appreciate the French!

Answer (score 2):

First a couple points

- The cell addresses you list are wrong I believe it should be P6, W6 not P3 and W1.
- If that is the same data repeated 3 times it would generally be better to set it up in one set of columns instead of 3
- -nb.si is countif in english and only takes 2 inputs a range and a criteria

So with that out of the way
If you are just counting cells can you just count the number of "H" in the row

`=countif(N6:AI6,"H")`

If you actually want to sum the values and not count them you could just offset the ranges you use

`=sumif(N6:AI6,"H",P6:AK6)`

Average would be

`=averageif(N6:AI6,"H",P6:AK6)`

These all assume you wouldn't see an H in other cells in the same row.

Comment: Hi gtwebb, thank you for pointing out that as you say correctly the values should be P6 and W6 - apologies for that that was my mistake. In terms of your second point I'm not sure I understand fully but let me tell you what I did understand so you could correct me if I'm wrong. You mean the data structure is repeated in which case it is that is a H or none H following followed by the number 2 columns to the right? But ,about your last sentence, the issue is that there might be H's in other cells in the same row. H is a condition and when present means count the figure 2 columns to right.

Comment: As I said in the comment to my post above please ignore this comment I left here because when I changed the cell format from text to number the formula applied itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean sum where you write count and agree some of your cell references seem incorrect, but suggest for:

SUM    `=(N6="H")*P6+(U6="H")*W6+(AB6="H")*AD6+(AI6="H")*AK6`
COUNT  `=(N6="H")+(U6="H")+(AB6="H")+(AI6="H")`

and for AVERAGE just SUM/COUNT from above.

Comment: Hi pnuts, as I commented above to gtwebb, I seem to be getting the same problem where I type in your formula and press enter but the formula stays in the excel spreadsheet without any values changing to an actual number; just the formula remains. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I feel I'm doing something so simple incorrectly so if so sorry about this but I'm doing the best I can given my knowledge and I'm eager to learn.

Comment: Again as I said above everything worked fine after changing cell from text to numbers and nice formula here which worked well so thanks for the help.